# How to format syslog date to logstash date timestamp format

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I'm trying to convert the syslog date format to a date timestamp that kibana recognizes, since it always appears as a string once the log is processed to elastic search.

This is what I've tried so far

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:/Elasitcity/File Destination/logs2/*.*"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "NUL"
         }
      }


filter {
        grok { 
            match => {"message" =>"%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:logstamp}.*POST for %{URIPATH:ServiceURI}"}
             }

         date {
    match => [ "logstamp", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]

                       }    
             }
output  {
    elasticsearch {
                    hosts => "localhost"
                    index => "nextgen2" 
                    document_type => "netboading"
              }
            stdout {}
        }
```

I'm trying to extract the date from this log below

```
Jun 12 04:27:35 1560306455 INCOMING: information 22.244.42.41 Jun 12 04:27:22 DPPRD01 [host_services][0x80e0013a][mpgw][info] source-https(IMS_SSL_29982): trans(2797190703)[12.6.1.16]: Received HTTP/1.1 POST for /services/NHgetInternetLimitsV1 from 10.6.17.166
```

I'm simply trying to get elastic search to acknowledge logstamp as a timestamp that kibana can use for dashboarding purposes.

Comment: It looks like it's working, when trying your configuration, `@timestamp` gets the following value `2019-06-12T02:27:35.000Z` which is equivalent to `Jun 12 04:27:35`, you might want to add a timezone parameter to the `date` filter, though.

Comment: On Kibana it doesn't seem to acknowledge the timestamp and proposes one - which i reject because I know it will use its own stamp based on when the log was integrated with elastic search. How do you tell that @timestamp is getting that value ?

Comment: `2019-06-12T02:27:35.000Z` = `Jun 12 04:27:35`... it speaks for itself (except for the timezone, which you can set to somewhere in CEST)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set your target like this:

```
date{
  match => ["logstamp", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss", "ISO8601"]
  timezone => "Europe/Berlin"
  target => "@timestamp"
}
```